# Powershell 2: Unable to suppress warning message

Tags: powershell, warnings

I am making a cmdlet call to 'set-distributiongroup' in powershell 2. I am simply setting the value of the parameter 'hiddenFromAddressListsEnabled' to a pre-defined boolean value.

However, no matter what I try, it displays a warning message if the boolean assignment is not actually changing the current value of 'hiddenFromAddressListsEnabled'.

Here is the main command I'm invoking:

```
set-DistributionGroup -identity TestGroup                  `
                      -hiddenFromAddressListsEnabled=$true
```

Let's semantically define what I have above as 'command'.

Now, I've tried adding several different variants, all with proper line-continuation and syntax. Here are those variants:

```
command > $null
command 2> $null
command -ErrorAction:silentlycontinue
command -ErrorVariable $throwAway
command -WarningAction:silentlycontinue
command -WarningVariable $throwAway
$var = command
```

Regardless of various combinations of one or more of the above, I still get a yellow WARNING: message spit to output. Specifically, this:

```
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of
'<xxxxxx>/Users/TestGroup' have been modified.
```

Any suggestions on a key concept I'm not understanding? I want the command to not produce this output, and I want it to silently continue if this occurs.

Thanks!!

Comment: Shouldn't `-hiddenFromAddressListsEnabled=$true` be `-hiddenFromAddressListsEnabled:$true` or `-hiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true`?

Comment: Yes. This was a typo I discovered immediately after making this post. However, the original problem still remains.

Answer (score 16):

I've been trying to suppress the warning messages when stopping a service:

```
WARNING: Waiting for service 'Service Description' to finish stopping...
```

The following worked for me:

```
Stop-Service $svc.Name -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a warning that cause problem why don't you set in your script `$WarningPreference` variable ?

```
PS C:\> $WarningPreference='silentlycontinue'
PS C:\> Write-Warning "coucou"
PS C:\> $WarningPreference='continue'
PS C:\> Write-Warning "coucou"
AVERTISSEMENT : coucou
```

Comment: Because, simply put, it did not work. I did exactly what you suggested, to set WarningPrefernce to silentlycontinue, but the warning still appeared on console anyways.

Answer (score 4):

just bumped this topic when searching on the issue, 
my case PowerShell v2 , only after setting

```
$WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
```

Write-Warning "blah" - returned me nothing... the parameter on the command didn't changed much too on my end.

Comment: thank you very much .this was the solution I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You may be hitting this bug: http://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/541500/warning-verbose-and-debug-streams-do-not-respect-action-preferences-the-way-they-should

Anyway, your command should look like:

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity TestGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

Comment: Hmmm - that's unfortunate. I have confirmed that my command looks identical to what you specified. It appears that if I really don't want this warning message to show up, then I need to wrap the call inside of some (grossly unnecessary) logic: "If the current value is already equal to what our desired value is, don't attempt the call". Sound about right?

Comment: yes, you can use Get-DistributionGroup to find the current value and set it if it doesn't meet your requirement. All of that because of a warning message?

Comment: yes, all of that because of a warning message. My code is going to operate on tens of thousands of entries, and being able to quickly scan a log file for problems will be critical. More critical than the efficiency gained by leaving out this type of check. I don't want 10,000 warning messages cluttering up the logs. What I do want is Microsoft to get their act together and make all forms of output handling consistent. :)

Comment: Can you try this, it works on my test VM: Set-Mailbox User1 -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $false -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

Comment: Unfortunately, I still got the warning written to console.:(

Comment: It worked for me on Exchange 2007 machine. By the way, what do you do to log the operation?

Answer (score 2):

Your command is wrong. Which is the the reason why you get a yellow error message. The command should look like:

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity TestGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true
```

Or

```
Set-Distributionaliste -Identity TestGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled:$true
```

But not

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity TestGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled=$true
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem with the Exchange Management Console in 2010. Problem is the EMC runs on PowerShell 2.0, which as stated before has some bugs around warning preferences.

I found a cheeky workaround was to run my script in a vanilla PowerShell 4.0 shell, and then import the EMC cmdlets and start a new remote PS session like so...

```
. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto
```

...then, **-WarningAction:SilentlyContinue** suddenly starts behaving itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
Set-DistributionGroup -Identity TestGroup -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true -WarningAction silentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into same issue, the following command seems to do the job (PS 3.0) :

```
Stop-Service<or whatever command> $svc.Name -WarningPreference SilentlyContinue
```

Don't know exactly what difference it makes with -WarningAction, though.

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke powershell versión 2.0, you should use "-WarningAction silentlyContinue". I was having the same issue, but in the script, if I invoke, for example "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -versión 2.0" , then you can use this parameter. I was trying on a scheduled task and using a ps1 script.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that:

```
PS C:\> {command} | Out-Null
```

For more Information: [Technet: Out-Null](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849716.aspx)

Comment: Why that downvote, this is a (my) official technique to suppress warnings. And it has not been presented here.

Comment: This does not work, for example, with the `Stop-Service` cmdlet.