# Disable Popups when Stoping/Starting Services in Batch File

Tags: service, batch-file, startup

I have a DOS batch file that Stops and Starts Windows services.  We ran into a situation where this activity failed.  When on the server, I launched the server's Service application.  I attempted to stop the service and got a popup message.  I am theorizing that the popup interactivity is why the stop of the service failed.  Is there a way, using the SC command, to disable the popup functionality?  Below is the code to stop the service.

sc \\%SERVER% stop %SERVICE_NAME%

Comment: @Lizz....the message was "Service not responding", it's not insufficient permissions because it runs correctly a lot of times.  There's some special case that is hanging it up.  It's running on Windows Server 2008R2 and it's running locally.

Comment: Try putting an "echo . | " (without quotes) before the command. This will echo a <return> to the message when failed or not. How easy is it to replicate the failure? What's the error log say when fails?

Answer (score 0):

Are you set on using `sc` to stop the service? Perhaps an alternate command would not be stopped by the error dialog. I would suggest trying `net stop "Service Name"`, however that would not allow you to stop the service remotely (without 3rd party tools).

If PowerShell is an option, try this (combining ideas from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392943/powershell-2-unable-to-suppress-warning-message) with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342486/using-powershell-to-stop-a-service-remotely-without-wmi-or-remoting)):

```
Start-Service -inputobject $(get-service -ComputerName %SERVER% -Name %SERVICE_NAME%) -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Also, you could try using `wmic` to stop the service like this:

```
wmic /node:"%SERVER%" service where name="%SERVICE_NAME%" call stopservice
```